# how to creat a toggle button for widget app

Tags: android, android-widget, imagebutton, togglebutton

this is the closet post I found to my question [How to make a toggle button for a widget android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966595/how-to-make-a-toggle-button-for-a-widget-android), however, I am looking for a more straight forward solution to this. 
Does any one have any straight forward solution to make a toggle button using image button to create a simple widget app?
I would greatly appreciate any advice on that.

I only need a simple toggle button which I can listen for the state change using a service class. Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to implement a toggle button and what way you choose really depends on what exactly you want to implement. For example, for a Wifi Toggle widget, if you are using an ImageButton, you can change the image itself by using something like 'remoteViews.setImageViewResource(_viewID, _resourceID)' as per the current Wifi state. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: yes exactly I want to create a very similar button to wifi widget button, which can switch on and off a service. I would appreciate if you could give me sample code on that. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments, I am posting sample relevant code below which can be used to change the image used in your widget:

```
                case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
                    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_normal_imagebutton, R.drawable.ic_widget_wifitimer_on);
                    break;
                case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING:
                    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_normal_imagebutton, R.drawable.ic_widget_wifitimer_transition);
                    break;
                case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
                    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_normal_imagebutton, R.drawable.ic_widget_wifitimer_off);
                    break;
                case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING:
                    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_normal_imagebutton, R.drawable.ic_widget_wifitimer_transition);
                    break;
                case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN:
                    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_normal_imagebutton, R.drawable.ic_widget_wifitimer_error);
                    break;
```

For a more thorough tutorial about creating homescreen widgets, you can visit:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html

It explains the whole process including how to update the widget with new information

Comment: Thanks Zeiger that link was really helpful :)